# Enthalpy of Ideal Monoatomic, Diatomic and Triatomic gases

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

We learnt today that in ideal gases (triatomic as an eg), we can find the internal energy, and their specific heats for constant pressure and volume

u=3RT

Differentiating with Temperature

Cv= 3R

Cp= Cv+ R
= 4R

So my question is can we simply integrate this with time and then say H=4RT? And apply the same thing for the other 2 gases?

Comment: You seem to be confusing time and temperature

Comment: @BySymmetry Thanks, i got it changed